# Wrapping C++ Function with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm getting a compiler error when I try to wrap a C++ function with Cython. I have a super simple C++ program that prints "Hello World," and I can't figure out how to resolve this error. I think it has to do with the data type assigned to the main function, but I'm not sure where to go from here...

hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

helloworld.pyx

```
cdef extern from "hello.c":
    cpdef main()
```

And finally, setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [Extension(
    "hello_world",
    sources=["helloworld.pyx"],
    language="c++",              # this causes Cython to create C++ source
    )]

setup(
    name='Hello World',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I get the following error: `helloworld.cpp(1253): error C2664: __Pyx_CFunc_object____to_py : cannot convert parameter 1 from int (__cdecl *)(void) to PyObject *(cdecl *)(void) None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type`

Comment: In your `helloworld.pyx` why do you have a `cpdef main()`? Change that to `int main()`. In general you shouldn't compile a C/C++ containing `main()` to a shared library.